# Software to create demo video of my android app

Tags: android, video, demo

I am sure i am not searching with the right keywords. What i want is, when the user open my app for the first time, i want to show a small demo video (10-15 secs) of how to do something on our app. Since I want to embed the video within the app, the output should be really small. 
Also if its desktop, mouse would be visible on the screencast. How to do that for the app to show users where they have to click. For example, if i click a button, how will the user see that i am touching that button.

I am thinking people would downvote, but seriously this is not my forte and i dont even know which keywords i should search for.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  But what I suggest is borrow someone else's phone, and make a video of yourself using your app.  Post it on YouTube.  And, you're done...  That's what many people do...

Answer (score 0):

You can run the app in the emulator and record the screen with any of all the existing programs for this. Most of them have the option to show/hide the mouse pointer and to highlight the clicks. Also it should be possible to choose a certain area of the screen.

If you are using Mac you can use QuickTime Player for this. Open and click on "New screen recording" or Ctrl+Command+N. If you use other OS, google for a screen recorder.

Some results:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/win-screen-recording-softwares/

http://icecreamapps.com/Screen-Recorder/

Anyway, most of the apps today show a small animation over the app, showing the use some of the most important elements. IMHO Something like that should be more convenient than embed a video.